# How to split a column value into multiple rows using Java transformation in Informatica PowerCenter

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Below input value for 4th column CUSTOMER_DETAILS can vary up to 30 values within symbol <>, but in this example only 5 values are considered.

INPUT:

```
Column 1      Column 2  Column 3    Column 4

CUSTOMER_ID    COUNTRY     REGION     CUSTOMER_DETAILS

1001           INDIA       ASIA_PACIFIC       <ACCOUNTID|CURRENCY|AMOUNT|RATING><AB00206R|INR|15099|-25><AB00356R|INR|17099|-20><AB168863|INR|15099|-27><AB16811M|INR|9599|-25><AB30216K|INR|20099|-50>
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
Column 1      Column 2     Column 3         Column 4     Column 5   Column 6 Column 7

CUSTOMER_ID    COUNTRY     REGION           ACCOUNTID    CURRENCY   AMOUNT   RATING

1001           INDIA       ASIA_PACIFIC       AB00206R       INR       15099    -25

1001           INDIA       ASIA_PACIFIC       AB00356R       INR       17099    -20

1001           INDIA       ASIA_PACIFIC       AB168863       INR       15099    -27

1001           INDIA       ASIA_PACIFIC       AB16811M       INR       95999    -25

1001           INDIA       ASIA_PACIFIC       AB30216K       INR       20099    -50
```

Comment: Can you please post the source data clearly. Its not properly defined

Comment: Seeing variable nature of the data in column 4, if possible load the data into some relational database and then  use REGEX.  to split the data first into <>, <>. And the use regex again to split the data based on |.  Using informatica this can be extremely tricky. But if you are comfortable with java transformation, then you can do this. Loop through column 4 in java trx. And inside the loop, split, slice as per  your need. terminate the loop smartly. Also, are you looking for code?

Comment: @Jim, i edited for you

Comment: @ Koushik, yes I am looking for Java code for this scenario to be used in Java transformation.